# how to convert csv to json using java with number value without quotes

Tags: java, jackson

I am trying to convert CSV to Java for that I am using jackson library. But when I am converting the value integer value is coming with quotes.  How to solve this problem.

Example of CSV

```
data1,data2
Test,1
NewTest,2
```

I am expecting

```
[{
    "data1": "Test1",
    "data2": 1
}, {
    "data1": "NewTest",
    "data2": 2
}]
```

But I am getting

```
[{
    "data1": "Test1",
    "data2": "1"
}, {
    "data1": "NewTest",
    "data2": "2"
}]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you use and that generates this result. Is the type of the second column `data2` a `String`?

Comment: please try @jsonrawvalue

Comment: Could you show you code how did you implement it?

Comment: Store data2 value in a Java numeric type like int, long, double, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't treat `1` and `"1"` the same way. You will have to convert it to a proper number.

```
try {
    return new JsonPrimitive(Long.parseLong(num)) // parse as a Long.
} catch (NumberFormatException e){
    return new JsonPrimitive(num); // it's not a number.
}
```

You may want to also add a check for Double.

Answer (score 0):

On the JSON *string* it still is easily done as:

```
String jsonWithNumbers(String json) {
    return json.replaceAll("(\"data2\": *)\"(\\d+)\"", "$1$2");
    //return json.replaceAll("(\"(data2|data4|data13)\": *)\"(\\d+)\"", "$1$2");
    //return json.replaceAll("(\"[^\"]+\": *)\"(\\d+)\"", "$1$2");
}
```